# Счётчик количества обращений к сервису

Tags: c#, service

Есть веб-сервис, и нужно сделать механизм, который проверяет (хранит) количество обращений к сервису. Например, 5 человек обратилось к сервису, и этот механизм хранит циферку 5. Это число (в примере, "5") должно быть доступно для чтения из сервиса.

Я думал сделать бинарный файлик, в котором хранить это число, а из сервиса по надобности дергать. Мне кажется этот подход малоэффективным. т.к. файл один, и его могут попытаться прочитать 100 человек, ошибка может быть, мне кажется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно поступить в данном случае?

Comment: А если это веб-сервис, там же наверняка какая-нибудь база крутится?

Comment: Да, как вариант пойдет - по крайней мере, не будет проблем с доступом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите выдавать пользователю данные о количестве обращений за все время работы, то вам не обойтись без базы данных (ну либо бинарные файлы, xml и прочее, но если речь именно о веб-сервисе, то бд видится наиболее логичным решением) - хранить эту информацию только в памяти возможно пожалуй лишь теоретически - рано или поздно ваш сервис остановится (или даже упадет)

С другой стороны, тысячу раз в минуту (или сколько там раз у вас будут запросы) гонять запросы к базе за одним числом - вариант так себе. Поэтому для приемлемой производительности имеет смысл держать некий кэш в памяти, по мере обращения к сервису инкрементировать его (не забывая о блокировке разумеется - тот самый lock, о котором сказано выше) и не забывать время от времени писать этот кэш в базу. 
Кроме того, если точность этого числа критична, то необходимо позаботиться о корректном его сохранении в случае исключений. ТО есть, если ваш сервис вдруг вздумает упасть, перед тем как отправить его на покой неплохо бы скинуть в базу тот самый кэш

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень поучительно. Каким  именно способом можно хранить кэш в памяти ? Я это не совсем понимаю. Как это на C# примерно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону `lock`:

```
object _sync = new object();

void Foo () {
    lock (_sync) {
        // только один поток может сюда попасть
    }
}
```

Если есть база данных, то можно хранить в ней. СУБД со всеми своими уровнями изоляции, транзакциями и прочей ненужной фигнёй не дадут испортить данные (если правильно пользоваться, конечно).

Comment: Про lock: я просто мало пользовался, поэтому спрошу: если кто-то залочил, остальные в этом месте будут ждать, или можно создать сторонний поток, задача которого увеличить этот счетчик?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Остальные будут ждать на входе. Так как блок кода одновременно может выполняться только из разных потоков, то lock не имеет смысла в случае наличия только одного потока. Если вы опасаетесь только за синхронизацию счётчика, то в lock следует разместить только увеличение счётчика.

Comment: Это я к тому, что веб-сервис, как правило, используется многими клиентами одновременно. В данном случае(автор написал ~100 чел) это не принципиально, но если количество возрастет?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Проблемы надо решать в порядке поступления. Если после профайлинга выяснится, что счётчик — узкое место, то можно будет дальше думать. Но у меня сомнения, что, во-первых, счётчик будет узким местом, во-вторых, что масштабирование реально понадобится.

Comment: Для увеличения числового счетчика эффективнее будет использовать `Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);`.

Comment: @andreycha Замечательно. А сериализовать когда?